# Magento 1 multi ajax request on one page checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

I added cart block to checkout and qty product are updated by ajax request.
for first request we do not have any problem but when shipping method or payment method are changed we get 403 error. I think the form key is already sent and expired . 
how I can fix this problem or how I can send ajax request without form key?

```
 var request2 = new Ajax.Request(
        '<?php echo mage::getUrl("base/index/getO") ?>',
        {
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                jQuery('.opc-wrapper-opc').html(response.responseText);

            }
        }
    );
```